# String content to HTML Convert. Encode to html in flutter dart

Tags: html, flutter, dart

How can I convert string to HTML encoded string in Flutter.

This is an example string

```
This is the sample text & special character 
also new line
```

I want to convert like this

```
This is the sample text &amp; special character <br> also new line
```

Not only `&amp;` I want all of the HTML entities available.
I found HTML to string everywhere But not String to HTML anywhere! I want reversed/opposite feature what `html_unescape:`  provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/HtmlEscape-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out how to do it with the Dart HtmlEscape class.

```
const HtmlEscape htmlEscape = HtmlEscape();
String unescaped = 'Text & subject'; // The text you want to convert
String escaped = htmlEscape.convert(unescaped);
print(escaped); // Text &amp; subject
```

Using flutter_html to preview with HTML template.

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as htmlparser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
...
String htmlData = """<div>
  <h1>Demo Page</h1>
  <p>This is a fantastic product that you should buy!</p>
  <h3>Features</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>It actually works</li>
    <li>It exists</li>
    <li>It doesn't cost much!</li>
  </ul>
  <!--You can pretty much put any html in here!-->
</div>""";
dom.Document document = htmlparser.parse(htmlData);
/// sanitize or query document here
Widget html = Html(
  document: document,
);
```