# Convert string/text to html in flutter

Tags: html, flutter

I am aware of the flutter_html package used for converting html to text but I am not aware of converting text to html. Is there anyone who has an idea how to? For example converting `"This is a client message."` to

```html
<p>This is a client message.</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String content to HTML Convert. Encode to html in flutter dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541964/string-content-to-html-convert-encode-to-html-in-flutter-dart)

Comment: Hi Diegod, No that does not answer my question as it convert string to escapes characters with special meaning into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use flutter_html

```
Html(shrinkWrap: true, data: content, style: {
    'body': Style(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    ),
    'p': Style(
         color: Color(0xFF0B1D54),
         fontSize: FontSize.larger,
         lineHeight: LineHeight.em(1.2),
         fontFamily: 'SourceSrifPro',
    ),
    'span': Style(
        fontFamily: 'SourceSrifPro',
        fontSize: FontSize.percent(98),
        color: Color(0xFF0B1D54),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        height: 1.3,
    ),
}),
```